# How to access the auto increment value in store method of resource controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I am making a blog. I want to concatenate the soon to be post id to the end of the post slug to make it unique but I can't find a way to access the auto increment value which was not sent through my form in request variable.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'body' => 'required'
    ));

    $cleaned = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', $request -> title);
    $cleaned = strtolower($cleaned);
    $pieces = explode(" ",$cleaned);
    $slug = implode("_", $pieces);
    $slug  = $slug."_".     <------;      //HERE IS THE PROBLEM

    $post = new Post;
    $post -> title = $request -> title;
    $post -> body = $request -> body;
    $post -> slug = $slug;

    $post -> save();

    Session::flash('success','Post Successful');

    return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reliably get the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value before saving the `$post`.

You have to add it afterwards:

```php
$slug = $slug."_";
$post = new Post;
[...]
$post->save();
$post->slug = $slug.$post->id;
$post->save();
```

The whole idea of including the `id` in the `slug` is not ideal. Maybe you should consider using a different approach.

Comment: do you think this is a faster approach compared to querying database for the same slugs in the database and then append a number to this slug if same slugs exist?

Comment: How do you use the `slug`? As an identifier in the URL?

Comment: yes. And to rephrase my question. Is it faster to save a database entry twice or search the database then return results and then compare with the slug we are working on?

Comment: Consider an URL schema like `example.com/posts/{id}/{slug}`. The URL is still SEO-friendly and the post can be identified by just the `id`. Like this, the `slug` doesn't have to be unique. Another advantage: If a `slug` changes, old URLs still work (you can 301-redirect users to the new URL).

Comment: Thats a better approach. I'll use it. Thank you!